# area onmouseover cursor appearance

Tags: javascript, html, onmouseover

I've got a map with `area` tags set up, for which I'd like to have a `onmouseover` event, changing the cursor's appearance to tell the user its clickable. But, there is a problem using safari:

Using `onmouseover="style.cursor = 'pointer';"` doesen't seem to work in the `area` tag. Not generally, as it totally triggers other things when hovering. Also safari lets me change its appearance using other ways, but with this combination it just doesen't...

```
<div class="desktop"> <img src="docs/docs_overview_desktop.jpg" usemap="#desktop"> <map name="desktop"> <area shape="rect" coords="2057.143,0,2742.857,960" onmouseover="style.cursor = 'pointer';" onclick="document.getElementById('lightboxSrc').src='docs/docs_000.jpg'; lightboxOpen();"> </map> </div>
```

Comment: provide a "sample not working code"

Comment: Plesase don't add code as a comment; instead click "Edit" below your post and add the code right in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Safari isn't always supporting the "general" functions that other browsers do these days. But still, I can hardly believe that they wouldn't support an onmouseover event, so it's probably the rest of the code that's causing the problem for it not to work.

---

If really want to use javascript to apply the styling for a pointer then try  to make it more specific like this:
`onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer';"`

---

But why use JavaScript when you want to add a styling? CSS alone would be enough just place this in your stylesheet and you can remove the whole inline onmouseover:

```
.desktop area:hover{
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

---

Or use an empty `href="#"`so the browsers sees it's a link and it shows the pointer by default.

Here's an example. Make sure your coordinates are in the image aswell of course!

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="desktop"> 
  <img src="docs/docs_overview_desktop.jpg" usemap="#desktop"> 
  <map name="desktop"> 
    <!-- Coords are from left uper corner (10px on the x and y axis) to the right bottom corner (90px on the x and y axis) -->
    <area shape="rect" coords="10,10,90,90" onclick="document.getElementById('lightboxSrc').src='docs/docs_000.jpg'; lightboxOpen();" href="#"> 
  </map> 
</div>
```

Comment: Sadly neither being more specific or using the second option you provided works. I've even changed the latter to affect the whole page, but it reverts the cursor to its default state as soon as the `area` is hovered.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: does the example in this documentation work in Safari with a pointer? If it does compare your code and the html and css from the example. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/area

Comment: It does, but only due to the use of `href`. I was trying to avoid this solution which would show a link preview in the bottom left, as I'm not really linking anything and just opening a simple lightbox

Comment: All right, I've updated the answer with a snippet from your original code not using the href. Does this snippet run like you want it to?

Comment: ...and I havent really found an alternative to `href="javascript:;` which changes the cursor, but doesen't link, as it reloads the page when `href` is undefined

Comment: Using firefox as an exmaple: Yes! Safari sadly still ruins the fun

Comment: All right. Then the href it is. You could keep the onclick and a ``href="#"`.

Comment: # is a valid option indeed, but sadly adds it to the url ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I guess I'll have to live with the link preview, but thank you so much for your time

Comment: ...solved it by adding `display: block;` to your first snipped